# running multiple php files within one php file

Tags: php, html

I want to run three php scripts one after another from one file. all the functions are already defined in each of the files so that when they are called upon (aka run) they will do things.
I thought the following code would run all 3 but it stops right after the first file is finished running. does anyone know why?

Thanks

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once ("file1.php");
require_once ("file2.php");
require_once ("file3.php");
?>
```

**EDIT WITH LAST FUNCTION RUN BEFORE END OF SCRIPT**

```
function sendPush ($date)
 {

$username='xxxx';
$password='xxxxx';
$database='xxxxx';

$device="";

$db= new mysqli('localhost', $username, $password, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo 'Error: Could not connect';
    //exit;

}


$query = "SELECT * FROM `DataTokens`";


$result = $db->query($query);
if ($result) {
    $num_results = $result->num_rows;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{

        if (!$row)
        {
            echo "No Token, insert into database";


        }


    $device= $row['Number'];


        // Put your device token here (without spaces):
        $deviceToken = $device;

        // Put your private key's passphrase here:
        $passphrase = 'XXXXXX';

        // Put your alert message here:
        $message = 'This is a test and its working';

        $i=1;
        $number= $i++;


        $ctx = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

        // Open a connection to the APNS server
        $fp = stream_socket_client(
            'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
            $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

        if (!$fp)
            exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

        echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

        // Create the payload body
        $body['aps'] = array(
            'alert' => $message,
            'sound' => 'default',
            'badge' => +1,
            'loc-key' => 'australia1'
            );


        // Encode the payload as JSON
        $payload = json_encode($body);

        // Build the binary notification
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        // Send it to the server
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

        if (!$result)
            echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
        else
            echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

        // Close the connection to the server
        fclose($fp);
    }

        }
```

**New Code**

replaced

```
  $result = $db->query($query);
if ($result) {
    $num_results = $result->num_rows;
```

with

```
//$result = $db->query($query);
if ($result = $db->query($query)) {

echo "we have a problem";

}

else
{

 $num_results = $result->num_rows;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{

         //blah blah
    }

    }
```

Comment: is there die(); or exit(); in file1.php?

Comment: There's no reason why the code you've posted would not run all the files unless there is something stopping the execution of the script on file1.php

Comment: @ConradWarhol thanks for the quick reply. just a fclose($fp) that closes the connection to mysql

Comment: do you require file2 in file1?

Comment: @user247245 No I do not. I thought as soon as it finished running file1.php that it would go back to the code posted above and start executing what was next which is file2.php

Comment: @AlexG It should.  Feel like posting a link to the code?  (pastebin, jsfiddle, etc)

Comment: display_errors is just a flag t/f.  1 is as true as 'on'

Comment: @Jake There is more code but I didn't want to bore you with it. The code above is the last function that gets called before the end of file1.php. For more background info, file1.php runs a script that sends a push notification to my app based on the device token and the message gets "successfully delivered" so I know it is not going through exit().Thanks in advance

Comment: I see a few exit functions. Can you do an echo right before the end of file1 and see if it prints? If it doesn't, you know it's dying before then. If it does, then I guess we'd need to debug further.

Comment: That is just a function declaration/definition.  Functions aren't executed when they are defined.  They are executed when they are called.  The fact that is the last function in your code does not dictate when it is called.  Maybe your first function is the last one to execute.  What I'm getting at is we can't diagnose your problem with the info we have.  Don't worry though; the vocabulary you need to ask good questions will come with more experience.

Comment: @Ansari thanks Ansari. I did an echo right at the end of script aka the function above and it displayed as it should meaning it did not hit an exit I believe. Any other ideas? thanks

Comment: I would advise writing all the functions in one file (called functions.php) and then write another file that is the logic controlling when each function is called, with what parameters, and what is done with the value (called driver.php)

Comment: I agree with Jake for better programming practice - separate the logic from the execution. To debug this though, did you make sure to add the echo after the function block and within the file? What about if you add it after the require_once line? What about at the beginning of file2?

Comment: @Jake Makes sense, great suggestion. I am quite new to programming and I will to do that in the future. Thank you for your help, if you would like to put that as a response I will accept it since there does not seem to be any other solution/way.

Comment: @Ansari I did make sure to do that. I just implemented your second suggestion and the echo never gets called after the first require_once line which confuses me even more now. file2 never gets called cause control never goes back to the require_once function. Any other ideas? If not thanks for all your help

Comment: @Jake I think I found the problem... this line: $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) gives me the following error which I think is exiting everything. Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object. Any suggestions on why this error is being called?

Comment: @Ansari I think I found the problem... this line: $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) gives me the following error which I think is exiting everything. Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object. Any suggestions on why this error is being called?

Comment: It means your DB query failed and $result is a NULL object. You didn't surround it with a try/catch thing nor did you die on error. So catch that error.

Comment: I was caught up in a regex writing blur for a minute.  A quick an easy fix is if($result = $db->query($Q)){echo "omg we have a problem";}

Comment: @Jake sorry if this is really beginner but can you please check my edited code to see if I did it right? Thanks so much

Comment: PHP lets us do assignment within if statements.  Take advantage of it.  I would suggest doing if($result = $db->query) rather than $result = $db-query; if ($result).  The rest of it looks pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `echo` statements at different parts of your code to figure out where control is being lost or where the program is exiting.

Make sure whenever you have an assignment to a variable from a command that could throw an exception, to catch  the exception if it occurs, or do something with it. Or at least verify for non-null ness (!is_null()) before using that object.

Comment: Topics to read up on: Exception handling, classes (and therefore objects), design patterns, best practices (dry, solid, kiss)